# Access crashing when coloring Excel cells

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am adding a feature to a MS Access DB. On my machine, the code never crashes. On other machines (including non-runtime copies of Access) a small change causes a crash. The code formats an exported query in Excel:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function format_status_report(ByVal filename As String, ByVal path As String)
    Dim obj_excel As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Const LAST_COL = 10

    last_col_char = Chr(LAST_COL + 64)
    Set obj_excel = New Excel.Application

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    obj_excel.Visible = False
    obj_excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    obj_excel.Workbooks.Open (path & filename)
    obj_excel.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = obj_excel.Workbooks(filename)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    num_rows = count_rows(ws)
    For i = 2 To num_rows
        If (ws.Cells(i, LAST_COL)) Then
            ws.Range("A" & Trim(Str(i)) & ":" & last_col_char & Trim(Str(i))).Interior.ColorIndex = 23
        Else
            ws.Range("A" & Trim(Str(i)) & ":" & last_col_char & Trim(Str(i))).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        End If
    Next

    ws.Range("A1:" & last_col_char & Trim(Str(1))).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
    For i = 1 To LAST_COL
        ws.Cells(1, i) = Replace(ws.Cells(1, i), "_", " ")
    Next

    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium16"
    ws.Columns(last_col_char).Hidden = True
    ws.Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 60
    ws.Rows("1:" & Trim(Str(num_rows))).AutoFit

    For Each Row In ws.Rows("1:" & Trim(Str(num_rows)))
        If Row.RowHeight < 30 Then
            Row.RowHeight = 30
        End If
    Next
    obj_excel.ScreenUpdating = True
    obj_excel.Visible = True
    wb.Save
    obj_excel.WindowState = xlMaximized
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    err_msg
    wb.Close
    obj_excel.Quit
End Function


Private Function count_rows(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Integer
    c = ws.Cells(1, 1)
    i = 0
    Do Until (Len(c) < 8)
        i = i + 1
        c = ws.Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Loop
    count_rows = i
End Function


Private Sub err_msg()
    MsgBox "Error occured? " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

The crash occurs if the colour values are changed in the following loop.

```
For i = 2 To num_rows
    If (ws.Cells(i, LAST_COL)) Then
        ws.Range("A" & Trim(Str(i)) & ":" & last_col_char & Trim(Str(i))).Interior.ColorIndex = 23
    Else
        ws.Range("A" & Trim(Str(i)) & ":" & last_col_char & Trim(Str(i))).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    End If
Next
```

Access will crash (except on my machine, where it runs) before a breakpoint is reached. Windows error message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: MSACCESS.EXE
  Application Version:  14.0.7162.5001
  Application Timestamp:    5626f514
  Fault Module Name:    MSVCR90.dll
  Fault Module Version: 9.0.30729.6161
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4dace5b9
  Exception Offset: 000320f0
  Exception Code:   c0000417
  Exception Data:   00000000
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 2f13
  Additional Information 2: 2f1305af727fc04ce417c25a567e9372
  Additional Information 3: a621
  Additional Information 4: a62129d4ea5fc426ef3a2d423daed40d
```

It seems to be some sort of graphics error. However, I'm lost as to what could cause ColorIndex = 23 and ColorIndex = 10 to be fine, while any other indices I've tried cause a crash. I've checked the references on startup on the runtime versions, and they appear to be fine.

EDIT: It looks like it is the Excel object reference that is causing problems, which is odd because my refcheck shows the full path to it on any machine, regardless of the version of MS Office. From experimenting, I have determined that the code runs as long as they are running the same version of Office as the reference selected in the dev copy.

Edit2: I failed to remember about the VBA.CreateObject function. Using this to create the Excel object rather than including a reference to the Excel library seems to fix all issues stemming from different office versions.

Comment: BEX is a DEP Branch EXecption error. Often caused by a buffer overflow. Exception c0000417 is STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER.  Color palate may be corrupt? try reseting the colors.

Comment: @HansUp I have been running a reference check on startup and all the references are there. However, I have noticed that the excel reference on my machine is Excel 12.0 Object Library and on the other (where it crashes) it is Excel 14.0 Object Library. Perhaps my problem is stemming from this? Is there a way to include a newer version of said reference without installing a newer version of excel?

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice you already said references were fine in the last paragraph of the question.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Hey no worries. Do you have any idea if the differences in library versions could be a problem?

Comment: My hunch would be that the differences in library versions could be the problem, so much as when i was developing in Access, my Office version was lower than everybody else's in the office, because of the references to Excel. Once a user opens up an Access, the app looks either for the Excel version OR LOWER. But if it refers to Excel 14.0 and the user has Excel 12.0 installed then Access wouldn't know where to look.

Comment: I'm unsure about that, @biatchstan.  The next thing I would do is add `Option Explicit` to the Declarations section of all your code modules: standard; form; report; and class modules.  Then take the ACCDB to one of the machines which has the full version of Access 2010 (instead of the runtime-only version) and where you've confirmed the crashes happen ... and then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  If you get a compile error then, that could be a useful clue.  If no error, give the other uses a copy of the ACCDB you compiled under Access 2010, and see if crashes persist ...

Comment: In that situation, the fact that you have Office 2007 while everyone else has 2010 should not be a factor.  Also please tell us if 2010 users have 64 bit Access instead of 32 bit.

Comment: Most of the users are using access runtime, and I'm unsure if it is 64bit. I'll have to double check what I'm running when I go in today, but I'm pretty sure it's the 64bit version.

Comment: @HansUp It seems that both my Access and the runtime copies are 32bit. However, most of the excel versions in the office are 64bit.

Comment: Hmm.  Still unsure what's going on, @biatchstan.  Assuming you find no compile errors when compiling with Access 2010 32 and 64 bit, think I would give the 32 bit Access users a copy which had been compiled under 32 bit 2010, and the 64 bit users one compiled under 64 bit Access.  That should rule out the possibility of any version or "bitness" mismatch issues.  Frankly that seems like a long shot to me, but should not be hugely expensive to answer.

Comment: @HansUp Thanks for all the suggestions. I've finally had a chance to work on the other machine with a full version of ms access. Referencing Excel 14 rather than Excel 12 seems to fix the crashing issues (except now the reference is missing on my machine lol). I think I'll leave it as is since it's finally working. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found (without understanding to much) that when Excel `Visible` property is set to `False`, it is safer to refer Cell's `Interior` property via the `Excel.Application` Object.
In your case:

```
For i = 2 To num_rows
    ws.Range("A" & Trim(Str(i)) & ":" & last_col_char & Trim(Str(i))).Select
    If (ws.Cells(i, LAST_COL)) Then
        obj_excel.Application.Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 23
    Else
        obj_excel.Application.Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @HansUp I would highly appreciate an explanation and/or proof why I understand wrong or right... ;)

Comment: Ah I was so hopeful this would work! Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it still keeps crashing :(. I am now able to work on the other dev machine that keeps getting the crash, so I'm going to uncomment my code line by line and find this damn bug

Comment: My observation would probably be true for the `Cells` collection too. If execution crashes at the `If (ws.Cells(i, LAST_COL))`try replacing it with `obj_excel.Application.ActiveWorkSheet.Cells(i, LAST_COL))`. Againn can't quite explain, just my experience...

Comment: @marlan Unfortunately, the code will crash the application without getting to any breakpoints. It's looking like the problem is related to the excel reference.